# I can not instantiate prefab of gameobject in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I did it many times,but maybe i forgot.I am trying to instantiate prefab,and scale it down but it doesnt take any effects.It only works if I scale original prefab,but then I am not able to Destroy this prefab.

```
public class PozicijaButona : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector2 pozicijaV;
    float x, y;
     Text tekstPozicije;
    List<Vector2> lista = new List<Vector2>();
   List<Sprite> slike1t, slike2t, slike3t, slike4t;
    public GameObject instantacija;
   private GameObject oznacenaSl;
    Vector3 skala;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        tekstPozicije = GameObject.Find("Canvas/pozicija").GetComponent<Text>();
        List<Vector2> lista = new List<Vector2>();
       slike1t= new List<Sprite>();
        for (int i = 0; i < HintoviMale.slikeT.Count; i++)
        {
            slike1t.Add(HintoviMale.slikeT[i]);
        }

        skala = transform.localScale;
        instantacija.transform.localScale = skala;
        Debug.Log("sjaa" + skala);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        
        pozicijaV = transform.position;
        x = transform.position.x;
        y = transform.position.y;
        string xT = x.ToString();
        string yT = y.ToString();
      //  tekstPozicije.text=xT+","+yT;
        tekstPozicije.text = pozicijaV.ToString();
      Destroy(oznacenaSl);
          
       

    }

    public void klikNaPoziciju()
    {
        Debug.Log("broj itema u slici"+HintoviMale.slikeT.Count);
       oznacenaSl =  Instantiate (instantacija, new Vector2(-0.7f, -3.4f), Quaternion.identity);
       // oznacenaSl.transform.localScale = skala;
        oznacenaSl.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite=HintoviMale.slikeT[0];
      
       

    }
}
```

I did it many times,but maybe i forgot.I am trying to instantiate prefab,and scale it down but it doesnt take any effects.It only works if I scale original prefab,but then I am not able to Destroy this prefab.

Comment: In your code, the function named "klikNaPoziciju" is never called. Also, you have commented out the line that would change the localScale of the object named "oznacenaSl".

Answer (score 2):

You never call your function named "klikNaPoziciju", which contains the Instantiate call. You also have commented out the line that changes the localScale of the object named "oznacenaSl".

Here is a simple example of instantiating an object and modifying it's localScale:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InstantiateObjectExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToInstantiate;

    private GameObject instantiatedObject;

    private void Awake()
    {
        CreateInstanceOfObject();
    }

    private void CreateInstanceOfObject()
    {
        instantiatedObject = Instantiate(objectToInstantiate, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

        instantiatedObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(2f, 2f, 1f);
    }
}
```

In the Unity Hierarchy, create an empty gameObject and attach the script to it. Then in the Inspector for the gameObject you just created, drag your prefab into the "Object to Instantiate" field.

[image: Instantiator Object Example]

**EDIT:**

OP mentioned they are calling their public method from an OnClick method in the Unity Editor. I'm not familiar with that approach, but another approach would be to use the OnMouseDown() function in your script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InstantiateObjectExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToInstantiate;

    private GameObject instantiatedObject;

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        CreateInstanceOfObject();
    }

    private void CreateInstanceOfObject()
    {
        Debug.Log("Creating instance!");

        instantiatedObject = Instantiate(objectToInstantiate, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

        instantiatedObject.transform.localScale = transform.localScale;
    }
}
```

For this to work, make sure the object you attach the script to has a collider attached to it. Clicking on the collider will trigger the OnMouseDown() function.

Comment: `You never call your function named "klikNaPoziciju"` .. well it is `public` so it is most probably called from somewhere else .. as the name suggests probably from a click

Comment: Ya, that may be the case. If so, I’ll need to know about it, so that I can revise my answer accordingly. Let’s wait and see what the OP says.

Comment: Ah sry i forgot to add that i am calling it from unity Editor in Onclick method.And i want to scale be the same as scale as object holding script.

Comment: @batakos, you could try using the OnMouseDown function in your script, instead of using the OnClick in the editor. I put an example in my answer above. I also tested it out in my own Unity editor and it worked.